# Retrieving results from IPython parallel hub database

Tags: database, cluster-computing, ipython, sungridengine, ipython-parallel

I've been running parallel jobs on a SGE cluster using IPython parallel. I submit my jobs and retrieve the results from the hub database (SQlite) at a later time when all the jobs have finished, using the jobs message ID. This worked fine till my controller crashed; on restarting the controller, I couldn't retrieve the jobs submitted to the old controller. I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/parallel/controller/hub.py", line 1281, in get_results
    raise KeyError('No such message: '+msg_id)
KeyError: u'No such message: 7f1996c0-deb0-4d7c-8782-619c86d2d064'
```

The database file (tasks.db) still exists and has the same size as before the hub crashed. So, I'm sure the results are in the database. Can I retrieve them using the new controller?
Also, if I use the bd_query command:

```
rc.db_query({'msg_id' : '7f1996c0-deb0-4d7c-8782-619c86d2d064'})
```

I get an empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, starting a Controller creates a new table (with a UUID).  If you want each Hub session to keep adding to the same table, add this line to your `ipcontroller-config.py`:

```
c.SQLiteDB.table = 'ipython-tasks' # or any other value
```

With that change, every subsequent Hub session will build on the same task history.  IPython 2.0 will make this [the default behavior](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4080).

Comment: Thanks! That's very useful. Is there a simple way to use my new controller to retrieve results from the jobs which were submitted using the old controller? The jobs took a while to run, and I don't want to resubmit them. I didn't explicitly store the UUID for the old controller.

Comment: You can list the tables in the database and get some info to figure out which one it was ([for example](https://gist.github.com/6295505)).  Then just set the `SQLiteDB.table` config to the UUID value you want to recover.